# python open a file and pass into a class object issue

Tags: python

I am no expert of python, and today I just wonder giving code like this:

```
class MyFile(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_file_path(cls, file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            return cls(f, file_path)

    @classmethod
    def from_file_object(cls, file_object):
        return cls(file_descriptor=file_object)

    def __init__(self, file_descriptor, file_path=None):
        self._file_path = file_path
        self._fd = file_descriptor
        self._parse()
```

My purpose is to let `with` to call `f.close()` automatically, however, I wonder if this kind of usage would cause any side effect like memory leak or any bad things like crash?

Comment: File will be closed after return from `from_file_path `. You'll return object which has closed file in its `_fd` attribute.

Comment: seems true, so despite the closed file, no other harm?

Comment: Yes, no other harm.